# getting error 401 (authentication error) in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I just created a WooCommerce site, and when I try to get json data it displays **error 401**. I tried to access it through postman with basic auth, and through the link:

```
(mysite)/wp-json/wc/v2/products?consumer_key=XXXX&consumer_secret=XXXX
```

with keys that I have generated in WP. In **both** cases I am getting the same error.

Config: 
legacy api enabled,
WC version 3.4.5,
WP version  4.9.8,
localhost server by Ampps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Woocommerce REST API 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49374319/woocommerce-rest-api-401)

Answer (score 3):

Add this to top of your `htaccess` file.

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

Answer (score 3):

Kindly use "Authorization" (besides the Parameter tab in Postman) choose Oath 1.0, then enter the consumer_key & consumer_secret then click the "SEND" button. That will work!

Answer (score 1):

solved:
the new legacy api has a different url to access woocommerce:
(mysite)/wc-api/v2/...

for more details: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v3.html?javascript#